# mips assembly working with strings

Tags: string, mips, mips32

i got a problem with mips assembly programming. I wanted to create a program which gives the reverse of the input string. It seems that I did not get exactly how to work with strings and how I can pick up the last letter and save it to another string adresse.

I will update my code fragment. Maybe someone can help me or can give me some advices.

Regards

My code:

```
## Programm soll eingegebenen String rückwärts wieder ausgeben.

.data

prompt:         .asciiz "Bitte geben Sie einen String ein! "
string_buffer:      .space 256


.text

## string ausgabe
la $a0, prompt
li $v0, 4 #print string
syscall

## string eingabe

la $a0, string_buffer
li $a1, 256
li $v0, 8 #read string
syscall

la $s0, string_buffer #adresse des eingegebenen strings
li $s1, 0 #counter

counter:
lb $t0, 0($s0) #in perm. register erstes zeichen geladen

beq $t0, \'\\0\', function #ende des strings
addi $s0, $s0, 1 #zum nächsten Zeichen inkrementieren
addi $s1, $s1, 1 #counter
j counter

function:
addi $s1, $s1, -1

add $s2, $s0, $s1
addi $s2, $s2, -1 #länge des strings

loop:

beqz $s2, exit #ende

sb $t1, 0($s2) #letztes zeichen des strings in $t1 gespeichert
addi $s2, $s2, -1

j loop

exit:

la $t3, ($t1) #versuch: hier sollte der umgekehrte string stehen
li $v0, 10 #the end
syscall
```

Comment: _"It seems that I did not get exactly how to work with strings"_ How did you come to that conclusion? Could you elaborate on exactly what the problem is that you're experiencing? A string (assuming ASCIIZ encoding) is just an array of bytes, where each byte is a character, and the final byte has the value 0 and acts as a terminator.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. let me try to formulate my answer in other words. How can I store bytes at any position of the array in another arrays? For example the given input is "hello" which is stored in string_buffer. No I want to save "hello" in another place. I do not know how I can save this string and load it at another place. 

I hope you can help me since I am desperate and need this urgent for my exam.

Comment: You set one register to the address you want to read from, and another register to the address you want to write to. Then you `lb` from the source address, and `sb` to the destination address.

Comment: I tried it but I got the message that the target is out of range. Can you maybe give me a short code example? I realy don't get where my fault is ...

Comment: Can you please write the comments in English?